# How to ensure that no manipulation to data records has been made

Tags: data-structures, hash

Let's say I have a transaction history, like this:

```
Transaction #1: Add 5
Transaction #2: Add 8
Transaction #3: Remove 2
Transaction #4: Cancel Transaction #2
```

Is there a way to guarantee that no transaction will ever be removed, or at least I will notice a missing transaction?

Basically I want to enforce to make a transaction to reverse an other transaction, instead of just deleting it.

Would saving a hash of the previous transaction help here?

Comment: What's your attack model? Random failures?

Comment: There's at least one whole research area around concurrent data storage. What have you read?

Comment: @adrianN User Manipulation. There should be no way to manipulate the data, without noticing it.

Comment: If the user can manipulate the file at will a simple hash won't do, maybe a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) helps.